Databricks DLT CDC/SCD - Taking the latest ID per day
Hi I'm creating a DLT pipeline which uses DLT CDC to implement SCD Type 1 to take the latest record using a datetime column which works with no issues:
@dlt.view
def users():
  return spark.readStream.table("source_table")

dlt.create_streaming_table("target_table")

dlt.apply_changes(
  target = "target_table",
  source = "source_table",
  keys = ["Id"],
  sequence_by = col("PublishDateTime"),
  stored_as_scd_type = 1
)

This gives me the following result:
SOURCE



Id
DateTime




123
100424 1717


123
100424 1710


164
100424 1704


167
100424 1619



TARGET



Id
DateTime




123
100424 1717


164
100424 1704


167
100424 1619



Essentially taking the latest record using ID and DateTime fields.
My question now is, how do I edit this code to take the LATEST record PER DAY. Please see below the example using the same table:
SOURCE



Id
DateTime
Date




123
100424 1717
100424


123
100424 1710
100424


123
110424 1717
110424


164
100424 1704
100424


164
110424 1728
110424


165
120424 1447
120424


165
120424 1316
120424



TARGET



Id
DateTime
Date




123
100424 1717
100424


123
110424 1717
110424


164
100424 1704
100424


164
110424 1728
110424


165
120424 1447
120424



As you can see, the target table takes the latest Id using datetime, but for EACH DAY not just the latest period.
I'm aware SCD Type 1 does not capture history so may not be the right option here but SCD Type 2 does but unsure of how to implement this. Would be eternally grateful for any advice here thanks

You apply_changes on date column also, so that it consider both id and date while processing data and gives records for each day and each id with latest updated values.
Code:
import dlt
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

@dlt.view()
def stg_table():
    df = spark.readStream.table("my_delta_table")
    return df

dlt.create_streaming_table("target_table")

dlt.apply_changes(
  target = "target_table",
  source = "stg_table",
  keys = ["Id","Date"],
  sequence_by = F.col("DateTime"),
  stored_as_scd_type = 1
)

I given the same sample data you provided.
Output:

Got 5 records in target table.


Thanks for this - I was considering this approach but didn't get chance to implement it yet and see. Another approach I considered would be to create another streaming table, which would filter on date = currentDate(). This meant that at the end of every day 11:59pm it would append the snapshot of the current day into the table - what are your thoughts on these approaches? Thanks again

Just tested this approach, works as expected thank you - marking this as solution

Yes you can use another staging table and do query on it but this would be the ideal approach.
